# Is walking a warm up?

Tags: walking, warm-up

1) Is walking a warm up before brisk walking? if not what warm up exercise we should do?

2) Is walking a warm up before jogging? if not then what warm up exercise we should do?

Comment: Sean's right. I would also add that neither brisk walking nor jogging require warm-up. Both exercises are non-stressing and can be started gradually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any form of movement that gets your blood moving in the parts of the body that you will be exercising without forcing them to exert themselves "cold" is a valid warm-up. If all you plan to do is a brisk walk, then a more leisurely stroll is a fine warm-up, certainly better than, say, couch-sitting. And many running programs suggest 5-10 minutes of brisk walking before running as a warm-up, so it sounds like you should be good there too.

Honestly, though, for someone in decent shape, I'd probably say that you're probably safe starting right with the brisk walk in either case, as that level of exercise is not very stressful, so there may be no need for extra warming up.